# BitTorrent - Automatically rename files

Tags: file-management, bittorrent

I have the data files for a torrent but because the file names differ I cannot simply load it into a client and join the swarm.

It would be very tedious to manually rename the files so I am looking for a tool or means to automate this.

I would think that in the metadata of the torrent file there is some type of hash/checksum for each file. Hence it should be possible to compute the hash for all files in a given directory and rename them to conform to the .torrent file.

Surely I am not the first to need something like this and there are existing solutions?

Comment: How many files are there? Messing with the .torrent file itself is even more tedious, IMHO. If there is some sort of sequence, an automatic renamer tool might help you.

Comment: I don't want to alter the torrent file in any way. I want to rename/hardlink my files so they correspond with everyone else's in the swarm.